# How to position a container view so it's the same distance from top of screen on iPhone 4 & iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, position, viewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a ScrollView and a ContainerView as a subview. I have positioned the ContainerView perfectly for iPhone 5 screen but when I load it on iPhone 4, some of the content that should be on screen is cut off.

How do I ensure that the container view shows the same amount of content from the bottom on both iPHone 4 and iPhone5 - I'm sorry if this is a broad question but if there's any other information I can provide then let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using layout constraints, just give the container view a fixed constraint to the top and bottom of the main view, and no fixed height. This will cause the view to expand and contract depending on the screen size. Depending where your scroll view is, one of the constraints might have to be to it, rather than the top or bottom of the screen (So, if the scroll view were on top, it would have a constraint to the top, a fixed height, and a spacing constraint to the container view below it. The container view would then just need one to the bottom of the superview).

Comment: I'm not using layout constraints in Auto Layout because when I use AutoLayout it messes up all my other views so I prefer to work without AutoLayout - is there any other option I have?

Comment: I'm sure there is another way, but I always use layout constraints, so I'm not so familiar with the other way any more. My suggestion would be to learn how to use layout constraints correctly so it doesn't mess up all your other views. Layout constraints are the way Apple is going, and at some point in the future, it might be the only way.